# How to add multiple servers in git repository

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I want to add multiple git servers in my repository and to push data to 1 server and fetching it from another server.
I am new to git.

Comment: For your next question, please be a little bit verbose and include what you tried so far. Googling something like this will usually yield a perfect solution.

Comment: Interesting to see how none of the answers actually got the question asked :)

Answer (score 2):

Git repositories know about other git repositories with *remotes*. A remote is basically just an entry in your `.git/config` file that remembers the URL of another git repository somewhere, and gives it a name.

When you run `git clone`, you're automatically given a remote called "origin" that remembers where you cloned from. You can add additional remotes like so:

```
git remote add some-name https://someserver/some/path.git
git remote add other-name https://otherserver/other/path.git
```

Git understands URLs in a variety of formats, including http(s), ssh, or even raw paths. Your servers should give you some indication of the URL to use.

Once you've defined your remotes, you can push or fetch data by using the remote names you've used:

```bash
# Push to "someserver"'s master branch
git push someserver master

# Fetch new work from "otherserver"
git fetch otherserver

# ... and merge its master branch in to the current branch:
git merge otherserver/master
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add as many remotes as you need:

```
git remote add fetchy git@fetchy.com:path/to/repo.git
git remote add pushy git@pushy.com:path/to/repo.git
```

Then, it's as simple as:

```
git fetch fetchy
git checkout -t fetchy/your-branch
# do work and commit changes
git push pushy your-branch
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the remotes to your repository. In your local repo, do this:

```
git remote add fetch_remote http://<link to remote>
git remote add push_remote http://<link to remote>
```

Verify by doing a `git remote -v`

You can then pull from and push to your remote repositories as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Get acqainted with the [Git Documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/).

For your question:

[git remote](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote)